# MaxMind GeoIP redirects everything?

Tags: php, redirect, geoip

i would like to redirect users from specific countries to another language.
Therefore I have uploaded MaxMind's GeoIPv6.dat and the geoip.inc in the folder of my webpage.

I am using following script in the header of index.php:

```
<?php

require_once('geoip.inc');

$gi = geoip_open('GeoIPv6.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);

$my_countries = array('AT', 'DE');
if (!in_array(strtolower($country), $my_countries))
{
header('Location: http://www.de.mywebsite.com');
}
else
{
header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com');
}
?>
```

Strangely, the script forwards everyone to de.mywebsite.com? Why is that? How can I solve this issue?

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting everyone *except* visitors from Germany and Austria to the German site.

You probably want

```
if (in_array(strtolower($country), $my_countries))
```

without the exclamation mark that inverts the condition.

Oh, and also what @Alex says in his answer.

Comment: LOL, I was just about to post, "Oh yeah, what @Pekka says, too." :)

Comment: @Alex we should be able to fuse our answers into one co-authored one :) Feel free to add my info into your answer if you want, I'll delete mine then.

Answer (score 1):

You're converting the country code to lowercase, but seeding your array with uppercase:

```
$my_countries = array('AT', 'DE');
if (!in_array(strtolower($country), $my_countries))
```